# Processing lists

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to figure out how to process a list like this:

```
[ [[4,6,7], [1,2,4,6]] , [[10,4,2,4], [1]] ]
```

This is a list of a list of list of integers

I want my function take take this list as input and return a list of integers that are in the list without duplicates. The result should be [4,6,7,1,2,10]. But I am having trouble in figuring out how to traverse it.

My first idea was to take a process each list of integer lists separately like:
1st = [ [4,6,7], [1,2,4,6] ]
2nd = [ [10,4,2,4] , [1] ] 
the main function will call another function to handle these recursively, but how will the function remember what was in the final list when it comes to handle the 2nd list? I dont think an accumulator will even work.

Comment: could you specify what your expected result should be?

Comment: Standard library solution: `nub . concat . concat`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of that list is `(Num a) => [[[a]]]` so you can just use `concat` to flatten the structure and then `nub` to remove duplicates:

```
nub . concat . concat $ [[[4,6,7], [1,2,4,6]], [[10,4,2,4], [1]]]
-- [4,6,7,1,2,10]
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/366f8fe4a1aa936f)

Depending on how the data is actually structured and based on statistical considerations it might be more efficient to remove duplicates within internal lists before concatenating.